# Hook on model.update/findOneAndUpdate mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to add a hook for update operations on a certain model with mongoose, but apparently I'm doing something wrong. The code that registers the hooks looks like this:

```
event.schema.post("update", function() {
  debug.w("updateing hook");
});

event.schema.post("findOneAndUpdate", function() {
  debug.w("findOne updating hook");
});
```

However, when using findOneAndUpdate of update, neither of the hooks gets called. Why could that be?

Note: "create" hooks *do* work, being registered in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

As part of the guess-a-param mongoose game, I have found that passing the post hook for `findOneAndUpdate` a doc param, gives me access to the freshly updated model. Here is how I am using it:

```
    mySchema.post('findOneAndUpdate', function(doc) { 
        console.log(`w00t. myModel.${doc._id} was updated. partay tyme?`)
    })
```